# How many Facebook Pixel Code can you have in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, code, facebook

How many facebook pixel codes can you have in Magento. I so that our marketing seo's put in Magento admin console in section Miscellaneous Scripts that there is more then one Pixel code e.g.

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
  code ...
  <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
   src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=12...&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
  /></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
  code ...
  <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
   src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=34...&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
  /></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
etc.
```

Also Pixel code does not work on page. Is it problem that is more than one Pixel code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One pixel is enough to work. Using more than one will probably make them stop tracking

There are several (and free) extensions available for implementing it, some examples:

https://www.apptrian.com/facebook-pixel-for-magento

https://marketplace.magento.com/cadence-cadence-fbpixel.html

https://github.com/gaugeinteractive/magento-facebook-pixel

https://github.com/Hevelop/Facebookpixel